# Removing every li tag before reaching the first p tag in string

Tags: php, regex, string, domdocument

Suppose I have a string containing some HTML. I want to remove every `li` tag before reaching the first `p` tag.

**How do I achieve something like that?**

Example string:

```
$str = "<img src='something.png'/>some_text_here<li>needs_to_be_removed</li>
        <li>also_needs_to_be_removed</li>some_other_text<p>finally</p>more_text_here
        <li>this_should_not_be_removed</li>";`
```

The first two `li` tags need to be removed.

Comment: @frosty I'm pretty bad at regx...

Comment: Some code would be appreciated...

Comment: @WisdmLabs array explode? I doubt it.. how would that work?

Comment: Regex is a poor tool for this. [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) is the preferred tool here

Comment: how did it even get there in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what you need. Simple and effective:

```
$mystring = "mystringwith<li>toberemovedstring</li><li>againremove</li><p>do not remove me</p>";//the string you provide
$findme   = '<li>';//the string you want to search in $mystring
$findpee = '<p>';//haha pee also where to end it
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);//first position of <li>
$pospee = strpos($mystring, $findpee);// then position of pee.. get it :)
//Then we remove it
$result=substr_replace ( $mystring ,"" , $pos, ($pospee-$pos));

    echo $result;
```

Edit: PHP sandbox

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e534259e2312682a04b64c6e3aae1521422aacd2

you can check the result here as well

Comment: :) _"$findpee"_ nice!

Comment: @VSG24 This also removes "some_other_text" in between the `</li>` and `<p>`, if that is what you want that is ok, but just to warn you :) (because it removes everything between the first `<li>` and the first `<p>`

Comment: @BasvanStein That's fine because in the real string there's nothing there anyway.

Comment: if you need to traverse an html or xml document?if not you dont need document parser for this task, imo. @BasvanStein he stated many li in between first <li> and first <p>

Comment: @VSG24 Ok, then that is for sure the fastest way.

Comment: @AtillaArdaAçıkgöz Props for finding a solution to this problem but what happens if the code changes? A parser could handle the change, while your code would require changes. That's why parsers are preferred. They are scalable.

Comment: @Machavity i did not say that parsers suck and i agree with you. :) but in that case this is just faster and simplier. as long as the criteria stay same this code works and when it changes you need to make some changes on parser as well. But like i said before i agree with you.

Comment: Somebody is looking for me?

Comment: @PeeHaa haha, this is getting out of control :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with PHP's `DOMdocument` using the below traversal function

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str);
$foundp = false;
showDOMNode($doc);
//now $doc contains the string you want
$newstr = $doc->saveHTML();


function showDOMNode(DOMNode &$domNode) {
    global $foundp;
    foreach ($domNode->childNodes as $node)
    {
        if ($node->nodeName == "li" && $foundp==false){
            //delete this node
            $domNode->removeChild($node);
        }
        else if ($node->nodeName == "p"){
            //stop here
            $foundp = true;
            return;
        }
        else if($node->hasChildNodes() && $foundp==false) {
            //recursively
            showDOMNode($node);
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With XPath:

```
$str = "<img src='something.png'/>some_text_here<li>needs_to_be_removed</li>
        <li>also_needs_to_be_removed</li>some_other_text<p>finally</p>more_text_here
        <li>this_should_not_be_removed</li>";

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('<div>' . $str .'</div>', LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
             // ^---------------^----- add a root element
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$lis = $xp->query('//p[1]/preceding-sibling::li');

foreach ($lis as $li) {
    $li->parentNode->removeChild($li);
}

$result = '';
// add each child node of the root element to the result
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0)->childNodes as $child) {
    $result .= $dom->saveHTML($child);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a php praser library will be much better and faster approach. I personally use this one https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser in my projects. it provides apis like

```
   $child->nextSibling()
   $content->innerHtml,
   $content->firstChild()
```

and more which can come in handy.

You can just do a foreach loop for all elements, register "li" tag inside them and if for third occurance, you find a "p" tag, you can just delete the $child->previousSibling();